# Using set for numeric value (batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp

I am attempting to write a batch program that will monitor cpu usage and stop a virus scan if cpu usage is high.  It will then restart the scan when cpu usage drops.

```
ECHO Checks if the total CPU usage is greater than 10%

SET scanEnd=0

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq scan32.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "scan32.exe">NUL
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
ECHO Program is running

wmic cpu get loadpercentage /value
FOR /f "tokens=2-3 delims==" %%b in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage /value') do (
echo %%b >> tempfile.txt
echo removed %%a)

SET /a load < tempfile.txt
DEL tempfile.txt
ECHO Load is "%load%"

IF load GEQ 10 (
ECHO High cpu usage
TSKILL scan32
SET scanEnd=1
))
PAUSE

IF "1" == "%scanEnd%" (
ECHO Scan not finished
IF load LSS 10 (
ECHO Restarting scan
"C:\Program Files\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise\scan32.exe"
SET scanEnd=0))
ECHO End of program
PAUSE
```

wmic returns the cpu usage in the form LoadPercentage=0 (or other number).  I filter this with the for loop and assign the digit to load.  For reasons I do not understand, there is something wrong with the assignment.  I am unable to echo the value (displays "") and no matter how I define high cpu usage, load passes the IF GEQ statement.  Even a 0% load is apparently greater than 10.  I know the problem is with set because I checked the tempfile.txt and it is filtered correctly, but I still have no idea why it's wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you assumed that `SET` command can read from stdin which is not the case.

You might simply assign the `FOR` variable into a new variable.

Try this

```
for /f "tokens=2-3 delims==" %%a in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage /value') do (
  set /a load=%%a
)
```

and then

```
if %load% geq 10 (
  echo load greater than 10%
)
```

---

but beware of the assignments inside `FOR` loops. You may need to *enable delayed expansion* for them to work correctly, in case there are more than one assignment in the loop. Eventhough this is not your case, you'd just need to adjust

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

and then refer to it using this optional syntax

```
if !load! geq 10 (
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to enable the delay but it worked perfectly.